# NgUpgrade: Can I use Angular2 Component in app bootstrapped with `ng-app`?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

If I want to use the Angular-upgrade module in my Angular1 application it seems like I have to bootstrap the whole app using Angular2's bootstrapping, including ditching the `ng-app` declaration. My team is very interested in graduating our apps' components over time to Angular 2, but touching the bootstrapping is a little too impactful for us at this moment.

In order to use the Upgrade Adapter do I *have* to transform the way my app bootstraps in order to use an Angular2 component? Is there anyway to use an Angular2 component in a full Angular1 app?

[Here's a great article that describes multiple scenarios](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html) for upgrading, but none of them leave the app bootstrapped as a normal Angular1 app.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is No.
From angular documentation

> Pure Angular 1 applications can be bootstrapped in two ways: By using
>   an ng-app directive somewhere on the HTML page, or by calling
>   angular.bootstrap from JavaScript. In Angular 2, only the second
>   method is possible - there is no ng-app in Angular 2. This is also the
>   case for hybrid applications. Therefore, it is a good preliminary step
>   to switch Angular 1 applications to use the JavaScript bootstrap
>   method even before switching them to hybrid mode.

For better understanding how upgrade works read this article from official documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html